# Why AndroidStudio doesnt see annotations

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Android Studio doesn't see these annotations, now I can't make my AsyncTask works. What's wrong?

```
import android.annotation.MainThread;
import android.annotation.Nullable;
import android.annotation.WorkerThread;
```

Comment: Did you import the annotation library `com.android.support:support-annotations`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `support-annotations` dependency in your `build.gradle` e.g

```
 dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'
 }
```

See here [Improve Code Inspection with Annotations](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html)

Comment: Still doesnt work. Now anyone new project i creates doesnt see these annotations

Comment: android.annotation.* is not from support library, it is from android.jar and contatins a lot of annotations marked with @hide javadoc attribute
So these annotations are unusable for common people, thanks google.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace using of android.annotation.* by android.support.annotation.*
see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are incorrectly using import code.

Instead of this:

```
import android.annotation.MainThread;
import android.annotation.Nullable;
import android.annotation.WorkerThread;
```

It should be:

```
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.WorkerThread;
```